# How can I empty a shifted stack?

Tags: javascript, html

In a script I have a stack with the following content pattern:

```
errorEvent=[["Title1","Content1"],["Title2,"Content2"]]
```

After the event gets processed (displayed in a box), the script should shift the whole stack by one:

```
errorEvent.shift()
```

The script processes the 1st element of the stack, then if the length of the stack is not 0 it calls again itself with the shifted stack.

---

The problem is that the `shift()` command leaves an element behind, with the value of undefined at the 0th place if we shift the last element of the stack, which causes that the script never gets emptied.

How can I remove the 0th value?

---

The option to work with the 0th element is not yet an option because the following function adds values to the stack only:

```js
function IssueError(id){
    errorEvent.push(events[id]||events[0]);
    //the events array contains the titles and the contents for the messages
    console.log("Issued:"+events[id||0][0]+","+events[id||0][1]);
    errorEvent.status="called";
    //triggers an event for the constantly running errMsg() function which displays the messages
}
```

Comment: "the shift() command leaves an element behind" False. The shift command will leave the array empty. `var ar = [1];
ar.shift();
console.log(ar.length);` **0**.

Comment: Using shift on an empty array returns `undefined`.

Comment: Seem like you're right. This case i can rewrite the code with using the 0th value. Thanks!